# RegisterForContextMenu ImageView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a floating context menu and I wonder if it's possible to activate this menu, by pressing the image in the ImageView?

My first problem is how to handle registerForContextMenu and the ImageView? I searched and find most examples with GridView and ListViews.

I have made the menu in xml and I should I use this method in the activity with a switch:

```
   @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like the others, you get your View in onCreateContextMenu, based on that you inflate the menu for the proper item.

```
registerForContextMenu(imageView);
```

The method above expects any View class.
Each time you call registerForContextMenu() for a different View, onCreateContextMenu() will be called for you to handle the proper menu creation.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    if (v.getId == R.id.youtImageView) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

Based on the item id you decide for which View the menu was clicked. You must me sure the id's of menu items for different views are not the same.
When the item from a context menu is clicked, you will receive the onContextItemSelected() callback with MenuItem that was clicked

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.image_menu_item_do_something:
            doSOmething();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: But should I not use the registerForContextMenu first to connect it with the id of the menu?

Comment: Of course. I thought that not obvious part is handling the menu, not registering. Answer updated.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure it's working? I'm using the AVD emulator and I guess the menu should be visible if I click in the image?

Comment: great answer, just thought I'd point out a tiny thing. It should be `v.getId()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have these methods in `onCreate`:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

registerForContextMenu(image);

image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openContextMenu(image);
            }
    });
```

And in `context_menu_main.xml`, that it looks similar to this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_option"
        android:title="@string/action_option_text" />

</menu>
```

Finally, you'll need to override these two methods as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_option:
            Log.e("TAG", "Option");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```